# Enviar formulario dinámico con angular

Tags: formularios, angular6

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy creando un formulario partir de objeto de javascript, este formulario consta de unas preguntas y unas respuestas por cada pregunta, el numero de preguntas puede variar al igual que las respuestas por pregunta. Por eso lo esto lo estoy construyendo de la siguiente forma.

```
    <form>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let cuestionario of formulario['cuestionario']">
        <div class="columns">
          <div class="column">
            <div class="control radio-list">
              <label class="label is-small is-required">{{cuestionario['pregunta']['texto_pregunta']}}</label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let respuesta of cuestionario['respuestas']">
                <label class="radio">
                  <input type="radio" name="{{cuestionario['pregunta']['id_pregunta']}}"
                         value="{{respuesta['id_respuesta']}}">{{respuesta['texto_respuesta']}}
                </label>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </form>
```

Quiero saber como puedo pasar las respuestas de este formulario a mi archivo `.ts` ya que desde allí debo enviar las respuestas del usuario al servidor.

Comment: ¿A qué **ts**? ¿Estás usando un servidor node.js o estás pensando en enviar datos a "un ts" que forma parte de tu proyecto angular? En ese último caso, no es posible ya que el archivo ts se está convirtiendo en el código javascript enviado al cliente y se ejecuta en el cliente. En caso de que estés usando node.js, ¿podrías compartir el código que va a recibir la petición y la configuración de la ruta? Una última opción que barajo es que quieras usar el evento "onsubmit" para capturar la información del formulario en el cliente (en ese ts) y desde allí enviar los datos al servidor.

Comment: En ese último caso debes leer la documentación: [NgForm (Listening for form submission)](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission). En la documentación (justo en el enlace que te proporciono) viene un ejemplo de cómo capturar el evento de envío para acceder a los datos del formulario.

Comment: Implemente lo que vi en el enlace que me recomendaste pero cuando hago el ´console.log´ en el método del archivo ´ts´ me aparece vació, como si el formulario no enviara ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta actualizando el código html e  incluyendo el código del archivo `ts` para poder indicarte qué está fallando.